# MySQL: Any good way to get cumulative counts and diff counts?

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have the following dataset.

```
+--------------------+
| item_id count date |
+--------------------+
| 000 10 2017-11-01  |
| 001 15 2017-11-01  |
| 002 2 2017-11-01   |
| 003 100 2017-11-01 |
| 000 20 2017-11-02  |
| 001 20 2017-11-02  |
| 002 22 2017-11-02  |
| 003 101 2017-11-02 |
| 000 30 2017-11-03  |
| 001 25 2017-11-03  |
| 002 42 2017-11-03  |
| 003 102 2017-11-03 |
| 000 40 2017-11-04  |
| 001 30 2017-11-04  |
| 002 62 2017-11-04  |
| 003 103 2017-11-04 |
+--------------------+
```

Is there any way to get cumulative counts and diff counts for each day between two arbitrary dates?
(As for the diff counts, if the selected dates are 2017-11-01 and 2017-11-04, the first diff count(2017-11-01) does not have to be included in the final SQL result as there is no data available before that date)

The following two tables are the expected SQL result.

***Cumulative Counts***

```
+--------------------+
| item_id count date |
+--------------------+
| 000 10 2017-11-01  |
| 000 30 2017-11-02  |
| 000 60 2017-11-03  |
| 000 100 2017-11-03 |
| 001 15 2017-11-01  |
| 001 35 2017-11-02  |
| 001 60 2017-11-03  |
| 001 90 2017-11-04  |
| 002 2 2017-11-01   |
| 002 24 2017-11-02  |
| 002 66 2017-11-03  |
| 002 128 2017-11-04 |
| 003 100 2017-11-01 |
| 003 201 2017-11-02 |
| 003 303 2017-11-03 |
| 003 406 2017-11-04 |
+--------------------+
```

***Diff Counts***

```
+--------------------+
| item_id count date |
+--------------------+
| 000 10 2017-11-02  |
| 000 10 2017-11-03  |
| 000 10 2017-11-04  |
| 001 5 2017-11-02   |
| 001 5 2017-11-03   |
| 001 5 2017-11-04   |
| 002 20 2017-11-02  |
| 002 20 2017-11-03  |
| 002 20 2017-11-04  |
| 003 1 2017-11-02   |
| 003 1 2017-11-03   |
| 003 1 2017-11-04   |
+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `MySQL` doesn't support windows `OLAP` functions(except the latest version), you can use variables.

**Cumulative SUM:**

```
set @item_id := 0;
set @val := 0;

select t.item_id, t.count, t.date, t.CSUM as CummulativeSUM
from (
select t1.*, 
       @val := if(@item_id=item_id, @val + t1.count, t1.count) as CSUM,
       @item_id := item_id
from table1 t1
order by t1.item_id, t1.date
    ) t;
```

*Result:*

```
+---------+-------+---------------------+----------------+
| item_id | count |        date         | CummulativeSUM |
+---------+-------+---------------------+----------------+
|       0 |    10 | 01.11.2017 00:00:00 |             10 |
|       0 |    20 | 02.11.2017 00:00:00 |             30 |
|       0 |    30 | 03.11.2017 00:00:00 |             60 |
|       0 |    40 | 04.11.2017 00:00:00 |            100 |
|       1 |    15 | 01.11.2017 00:00:00 |             15 |
|       1 |    20 | 02.11.2017 00:00:00 |             35 |
|       1 |    25 | 03.11.2017 00:00:00 |             60 |
|       1 |    30 | 04.11.2017 00:00:00 |             90 |
|       2 |     2 | 01.11.2017 00:00:00 |              2 |
|       2 |    22 | 02.11.2017 00:00:00 |             24 |
|       2 |    42 | 03.11.2017 00:00:00 |             66 |
|       2 |    62 | 04.11.2017 00:00:00 |            128 |
|       3 |   100 | 01.11.2017 00:00:00 |            100 |
|       3 |   101 | 02.11.2017 00:00:00 |            201 |
|       3 |   102 | 03.11.2017 00:00:00 |            303 |
|       3 |   103 | 04.11.2017 00:00:00 |            406 |
+---------+-------+---------------------+----------------+
```

**[Cumulative SUM DEMO](http://rextester.com/BUU10810)**

---

**DIFF Count:**

```
set @item_id1 := 0;
set @val1 := 0; 
set @count := 0;

select t.item_id, t.count, t.date, t.CSUM as diffSUM
from (
select t1.*, 
       @val1 := if(@item_id1=item_id, t1.count - @count, t1.count) as CSUM,
       @item_id1 := item_id,
       @count := count
from table1 t1
order by t1.item_id, t1.date
    ) t
where count <> csum;
```

*Result:*

```
+---------+-------+---------------------+-----------+
| item_id | count |        date         | diffCount |
+---------+-------+---------------------+-----------+
|       0 |    20 | 02.11.2017 00:00:00 |        10 |
|       0 |    30 | 03.11.2017 00:00:00 |        10 |
|       0 |    40 | 04.11.2017 00:00:00 |        10 |
|       1 |    20 | 02.11.2017 00:00:00 |         5 |
|       1 |    25 | 03.11.2017 00:00:00 |         5 |
|       1 |    30 | 04.11.2017 00:00:00 |         5 |
|       2 |    22 | 02.11.2017 00:00:00 |        20 |
|       2 |    42 | 03.11.2017 00:00:00 |        20 |
|       2 |    62 | 04.11.2017 00:00:00 |        20 |
|       3 |   101 | 02.11.2017 00:00:00 |         1 |
|       3 |   102 | 03.11.2017 00:00:00 |         1 |
|       3 |   103 | 04.11.2017 00:00:00 |         1 |
+---------+-------+---------------------+-----------+
```

**[DIFF Count DEMO](http://rextester.com/OKGT50942)**

Comment: Thank you for your input. The cumulative one worked, but the other one throws an error saying "Unknown column 'count' in 'field list'". I could not figure out how to resolve this error...

Comment: @d.s: Kindly check the attached demo.. It works like a charm :-)

Comment: figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this, see if its any good. This is the ms sql server approach, but hopefully similar enough to help.

```
DECLARE @Tbl AS TABLE (item CHAR(3)
                      ,count INT
                      ,date DATE
                      )
INSERT  INTO @Tbl
        (item, count, date)
VALUES  ('000', 10, '2017-11-01'),
        ('001', 15, '2017-11-01'),
        ('002', 2, '2017-11-01'),
        ('003', 100, '2017-11-01'),
        ('000', 20, '2017-11-02'),
        ('001', 20, '2017-11-02'),
        ('002', 22, '2017-11-02'),
        ('003', 101, '2017-11-02'),
        ('000', 30, '2017-11-03'),
        ('001', 25, '2017-11-03'),
        ('002', 42, '2017-11-03'),
        ('003', 102, '2017-11-03'),
        ('000', 40, '2017-11-04'),
        ('001', 30, '2017-11-04'),
        ('002', 62, '2017-11-04'),
        ('003', 103, '2017-11-04');
WITH    cte
          AS (SELECT    *
              ,         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY date) RN
              FROM      @Tbl
             )
    SELECT  A.item
     ,      A.count
     ,      A.date
     ,      C.Cume
    FROM    cte A
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUM(count) Cume
                 FROM   cte B
                 WHERE  A.item = B.item
                        AND A.RN >= B.RN
                ) C
```

This is a generic example of how to get cume totals against your data.  Adding date ranges in should be simple enough. Using the row number technique you can replace the sum of previous to be difference from previous.

If your still stuck after looking through this, then let me know and I can code that up too, but better if you can understand whats been done here and apply your own solution.

Comment: `MySQL`(excepts the latest version) doesn't support OLAP functions :-)